# How to get the longest coherent string from a substring in PHP?

Tags: php, ipv6

Currently I'm trying to compress IPv6-Addresses using PHP. As known, the longest coherent String of empty blocks (`0000`) can be replaced with `::` (for more information see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation)). This compression is only allowed once. How to get the longest coherent string from the substring `0000` to replace it with double colon? Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: It actually involves more than just the longest block of zeroes if you want to convert an IPv6 address to the canonical form. [RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952) gives you all the rules. For example, what if you have two equal lengths of zero blocks? In that case, the leftmost block is compressed. Regular expressions can be helpful for this.